# Inequality between variances

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable. Let $a$ and $b$ be two constants such that $a < b$.

Define $Z=\min(\max(a,X),b)$. How can we show that: $\text{var}[Z]≤\text{var}[X]$?

I think a key step to prove this result is to first show that given a random variable $Y$, $\text{var}[Y^+]≤\text{var}[Y]$, where $Y^+=\max(0,Y)$. Unfortunately, I didn't find any way to prove this.

Comment: Is it correct to conclude that $$Z=\begin{cases}X,& a \leq X \leq b,\\a,& X < a,\\b& X > b\end{cases}$$ and so the distribution of $Z$ has finite support that may be a subset of the support of the distribution of $X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show it as you suggest. Note that $X=X^++X^-$ where $X^+=\max(X,0)$ and $X^-=\min(X,0)$. Then $X^+\geq 0$, $X^-\leq 0$ and $X^+X^-=0$ (and therefore  $\mathbb{E}(X^+)\geq 0$ and $\mathbb{E}(X^-)\leq 0$). A direct computation shows $$\operatorname{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-\mathbb{E}(X)^2\geq\operatorname{Var}(X^+)+\operatorname{Var}(X^-).$$

Now use that $\max(X,a)=\max(X-a,0)+a$ and $\min(X,b)=\min(X-b,0)+b$.